# How to create a working one to many relationship

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

For my Spring Boot application I have two tables in the database[image] and [image]
My issue is that I can't make this one to many relationship works.
This is my code for Group and GroupType classes:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "GROUPTYPE")
public class GroupType {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int groupTypeId;
    private String fullName;
    private boolean active;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "GroupTypeId")
    private Group group;

}
```

and

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "GROUP")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int groupId;

    private String fullName;

    private boolean active;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
    private List<GroupType> groupTypes;

}
```

I get an error of this type:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet....
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
```

I watched some videos but I still can't find a solution

Answer (score 0):

The word `GROUP` is a reserved keyword in both "MySql" and "PostgreSql", and hence you need to rename your table to something else:

```
@Table(name = "GROUP") // <- change the name
public class Group {

    // ...
}
```

Generally, you'd pay attention to naming tables and fields, and avoiding using reserved keyword of the underlying DB vendor.

Reference: [MySql Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-G), and [PostgreSql Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html)